# Nested foreach performance in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, loops, foreach

I have the following nested foreach loop which is taking approximately 17 seconds to operate in a controller of an ASP.NET MVC website and am looking for suggestions to reduce that time.

- AllObj1 is a list of approximately 1000 objects of ObjectType1.
- AllObj2 is a list of approximately 10 objects of ObjectType2.

The purpose of the foreach is to compare the contents of both lists for matching ID values, and adding that subset to a 3rd list.

```
foreach (ObjectType1 obj1 in AllObj1) {                    
    foreach (ObjectType2 obj2 in AllObj2) {                        
        if (obj1.ID == obj2.ID) {                            
            NewList.Add(obj1.ObjectVariable);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, in this code, this can mean up to 10,000 comparisons are being made and is exceptionally slow, increasing a 2 second page load to 19 seconds running on a high end Azure deployment.

Any suggestions on how to replace this piece of code with something faster?

Comment: did you try with where in linq ?

Comment: I have not. Do you have a code excerpt describing what you mean?

Comment: try var newlist = Allobj1.where(x=>  AllObj2.select(x=>x.ID).Contains(x.ID)); just make a try ? i didn't try this out.

Comment: I think you meant to have different variable names before the lamba expressions on some of those?

Comment: sorry i don't understand your comment.

Comment: Nevermind, that worked. I will have to test the performance. Thanks.

Comment: can i post it as a answer ?

Comment: Something you are not showing is making it slow.  If I just create 2 lists (1000, 10) of objects that have an int ID, and compare them, your loop takes 3 ms to complete.  A linq query like @FrebinFrancis posted takes just under 2ms to complete.  If these are IEnumerables, then what is the source.

Comment: If I comment out this code block, the page loads in 2 seconds, adding it back adds 17 seconds onto the load time. I can assure you, it is indeed this that is causing the delay.

Comment: If I take the code you posted, it runs in 3ms with list of a custom object with an ID of integer, so there is something else contributing to the slowness.  What is the source of AllObj1 and AllObj2?

Comment: @mansonitefirefox John Koerner is right. I had also benchmarked it and it indeed ran in 3ms with two "in-memory" lists. Are you sure that AllObj1 and AllObj2 are of type List<> instead of IEnumerable<> or IQueryable<>? You may be hitting the database in-between those for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was me I'd start from here. (Using linq .join)

If its slow there's potentially something deeper going on (is accessing the properties causing a dB hit?).

(Excuse typeos etc, am on a tablet which isn't brilliant for writing code)

```
var newlist = Allobj1.join(allobj2, 
    a1=>a1.Id,
    a2=> a2.Id, 
    (a1, a2) => a1.objectVariable)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a LINQ query to get the common ID values

```
var common = AllObj1.Select(x => x.ID).Intersect(AllObj2.Select(y => y.ID));
```

and then another to generate the new list

```
var results = AllObj1.Where(x => common.Contains(x.ID)).Select(x => x.ObjectVariable);
```

Comment: Increased load time by 1 second to do is this way. Still looking for an answer.

Comment: What? I created 1000 of type 1 and 10 of type 2 and the whole thing take a few milliseconds.

Comment: eventually got it to work, reduced computation time by 30%. Will require more work, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
var idHash = new HashSet<int>(AllObj2.Select(x => x.ID));
NewList.AddRange(AllObj1.Where(x => idHash.Contains(x.ID));
```

(I've assumed that `ID` is an `int`, but if not change the `HashSet<int>` to whatever type you actually need.)

By using a `HashSet<>` this should be very fast.

Comment: Error 5 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Project.Models.ObjectType2>.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.Models.ObjectType2>)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\ [User]\Project\Controllers\ControllerX.cs 261 17 Project

Comment: @mansonitefirefox - Surely you can solve that one. The type of `NewList` is probably `List<ObjectType2>` - perhaps it should be `List<ObjectType1>`. If not then swap `AllObj2` and `AllObj1` in my answer.